# Areas with a special property (five only)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**Replace the question mark. Explain why.**

---

[image]

Comment: No idea why making minor progress on this made me want to do CC, but "Data server, regularly on cars (3)", "Data entry method, regularly on cars (3)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the last image should look like this:

> [image: Arrow pointing west, with number 23]

Because the five areas being referred to in the title are:

> the **five US states whose names contain a compass direction**, i.e. North Carolina, South Carolina, North Dakota, South Dakota, and West Virginia.

These are being clued by:

> 1. An arrow indicating the compass direction;
>
>  2. The atomic number of a chemical element from the Periodic Table where certain letters in the element's name are highlighted that **also appear in the non-compass part of the state's name**.

To explain further:

> - Element 6 is **CAR**b**ON** - the highlighted letters C, A, R, O and N all appear in **CARO**LI**N**A.
>
>  - Element 110 is **DA**RMS**TA**DTIUM - the highlighted letters D, A, T and a second A all appear in **DA**KO**TA**.
>
>  And this means that the 8-letter element which matches the blue/black letter pattern that must have been used to clue the name of 'West Virginia' is:
>
>  - Element 23: **VAN**AD**I**UM - as the highlighted letters V, A, N and I all appear in **VI**RGI**N**I**A** (just not in the same order).

Comment: Everything looks good, this is the intended answer. Good job!